# Automate sql express 2016 edition download and installation

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-express

I am planning to download and install SQL express edition 2016 using powershell and wanted to automate the process. I tried chocolatey package manager for this purpose. I created a configuration.ini for providing all the configuration details and updated the instance name and instance id and tried the following commands:

> ```
> > $chocopath = 'c:\programdata\chocolatey' if ((test-path $chocopath)
> > -eq $false){
> >     set-executionpolicy remotesigned -force
> >     iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')) }
> > set-content -Value $Source -Path 'configurationfile.ini' 
> > choco install mssqlserver2016expressadv
> > --params='/ConfigurationFile="ConfigurationFile.ini"' -y
> > 
> > Remove-Item configurationfile.ini -Force
> ```

But with this logic, i am unable to update my created configuration settings during installation and it choco package manager always considers default parameters. Any guidance on this will be highly appreciated or if any other strategy i can use to automate this whole process let me know.

Error log:

```
2 [DEBUG] - Elevating permissions and running ["C:\Users\medadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\chocolatey\chocolatey\MsSqlServer2016ExpressAdv\SQLEXPR\setup.exe" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /Q /ACTION=install /INSTANCEID=SQLEXPRESS /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /UPDATEENABLED=FALSE ]. This may take a while, depending on the statements.
2021-11-12 12:14:23,769 8412 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: SQL Server 2016 transmits information about your installation experience, as well as other usage and performance data, to Microsoft to help improve the product. To learn more about SQL Server 2016 data processing and privacy controls, please see the Privacy Statement.
2021-11-12 12:14:23,771 8412 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: The following error occurred:
2021-11-12 12:14:23,790 8412 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Instance name 'SQLEXPRESS' is already in use. To continue, specify a unique instance name.
```

Comment: Unfamiliar with Choco, but, the error log is stating that Sql Server Express is already installed where you are trying to install it.  Have you tried changing the code to install a "named" instance instead of a "default" one?

Comment: yes in configuration.ini file i am mentioning the new instance name. Apart from choco, if you have any other solution also you can mention here.

Comment: If it were me, I would most likely uninstall all traces of Sql Server.  If Sql Server was never even installed, I would most likely lean on there being an issue with the choco automation software and troubleshoot from that angle.